# setUserVisibleHint method never called with tabhost fragment

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have parent fragment which is implemented with tabhost and having two child fragments A and B fragment , And I want to call a method when the child fragment is visible to the user , I have used setUserVisibleHint which is a Override method. but its never called during the child fragement A or B appears to the user.

The following is the code which  have used :

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        Log.d("setUserVisibleHint***called",""+isVisibleToUser);

        if(isVisibleToUser){
          calltoMethod();

          }



    }
```

And Parent fragment code is :

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment{

private TabHost planTabHost;
LinearLayout tabMainLayout;
private static View plansView;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
plansView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plansfragment, container, false);
planTabHost = (TabHost)plansView. findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    planTabHost.setup();

            planTabHost.addTab(planTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("A").setContent(R.id.Afragment));
            planTabHost.addTab(planTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("B").setContent(R.id.Bfragment));



planTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TabHost.OnTabChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html)

To know about the current selected tab position.

```
 planTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         
                    Log.i("Selected Tab", "index::" + planTabHost.getCurrentTab());
                }       
            });
```

Comment: setOnTabChangedListner method is called only when user taps on the tab . but I want load B fragment without user interaction.